# celery, ignore task which is past overdue?

Tags: task, celery

When django server is running and celery is not running, 
periodic tasks are generated.

When I resume celery, I see the past tasks are run.
Can I mark specific tasks not to be run if past-due?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `expires` option of [`Task.apply_async`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) will work for you.

For example your task may looks like this:

```py
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=15), expires=15)
def update_something():
    # do something
```

It's simple solution.

More customisable solution may be follows. You can save result of your task to cache (e.g. in Redis), and while result of this task is in cache all new tasks are returning just cached value. This solution is very flexible, because you can store all information in cache to decide what to do next (e.g. get value from cache, or rerun task).